# Adding Parameter for setting initial background color

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
class White extends JFrame  
{ public White()  
 { getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white); }  
}   
class TestWhite  
{ public static void main(String [] args)  
 { White w;  
 w = new White();  
 w.setSize(200,220);  
 w.setTitle("White");  
 w.setVisible(true);  
 w.addWindowListener  
 (new WindowAdapter()  
 { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)  
 { System.exit(0); }  
 });  
 }  
}
```

displays a window with a white background.

How to Add a parameter to the constructor to specify the intial background colour of
the window?

Comment: You're missing the basics here. I suggest you to read some general OOP tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in White class with overloaded constructor

```
public White(Color color) { getContentPane().setBackground(color); }
```

and instantiate using

```
White  w = new White(Color.white);
```